# Is the thermal expansion equation wrong?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've learned in my physics class the thermal expansion formula

$$l=l₀(1+αΔT)$$

Imagine for a second that you take rod and heat it up some amount ΔT, then cool it down -ΔT so that it is back at it's original temperature.

$$l=l₁(1-αΔT)$$,     $$l₁=l₀(1+αΔT)$$

We can substitute to get:

$$l=l₀(1+αΔT)(1-αΔT)$$

And simplify to get:

$$l=l_0(1-(αΔT)²)$$

This would mean that when I heat something up and cool it back down again it shrunk overall! Am I doing something incorrectly, or can I just use heating and cooling to shrink things forever like some kind of supervillan.

Comment: Hi everybody -- as a friendly reminder, please do not answer in the comments. Comments are for suggesting improvements or seeking clarifications only. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Coefficient of linear expansion in it's differential form is:

$$\alpha (T) = \frac{1}{\ell}\cdot\frac {d\ell}{dT} $$

When you solve this equation, while assuming temperature independent $\alpha$ (i.e., constant), you get:

$$\left [\ln \ell \right]_{\ell_0}^{\ell'}= \alpha \Delta T$$

$$\implies \ell ' =\ell _0 e^{\alpha \Delta T}$$

Here note that if $\alpha$ is very small then we can approximate:

$$e^{\alpha \Delta T} \approx 1+\alpha \Delta T$$

Therefore

$$\ell ' = \ell_0 (1+ \alpha \Delta)$$

Now if you go from $\ell_0$ to $\ell'$ with temperature change from $T_0$ to $T'$ you get:

$$\ell ' =\ell _0 e^{\alpha \Delta T} \tag 1$$

Reverting this back with $\ell '$ at $T'$ and $\ell''$ at $T_0$ you get:

$$\ell '' =\ell ' e^{-\alpha \Delta T} \tag 2$$

Substituting $\ell'$ from $(1)$ into $(2)$ we get:

$$\ell'' = \ell_0$$

So it turns out that the equation which you were using is an approximation.